# group role sync and membership role sync - does one take priority over the other?

Tags: drupal, civimember, groups, roles

I'm looking at a scenario where adding a contact to a group gives them a new Drupal role, but I also want to remove that role if a membership (which is part of a separate workflow) expires. Would that work using the two sync modules, or would the group/role sync simply re-apply the role when the user next logs in?

Comment: So your system wouldn't cope with the member who is in the group having both roles?

Comment: I think you may have it there @petednz - thanks.

Comment: i will add as answer then

Comment: care to accept the below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to rejig your roles so that the outcome you need can be delivered by letting Members have one Role and people in the Group have another Role. It seems like a 'cumulative' approach to permissions and roles could work for you.